# Binary search tree successor

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

How can I change the following function to let me return the **successor of an integer k** to a level between **h1** and **h2**? h1 and h2 are ranges for example h1 = 0 and h2=3, I want the successor of k who is at depths between 0 and 3

```
//BST declaration
struct node
{
   int key;
   struct node *left;//pointer to left
   struct node *right;// pointer to right
};

struct node *successor(struct node *T, int k, int h1, int h2)
{
   struct node *z = T;
   struct node *y = NULL;//successor candidate
   if(T!=NULL)
   {
      while(z!=NULL && z->key!=NULL)
      {
        if(k > z->key)
            z = z->right;//If k is greater than the root then I move to the right
        else if(k < z->key)
        {
            y = z;//updates the successor of his father
            z = z->left;//If k is less than the root then I move to the left
        }
       }
      if(z!=NULL && z->right!=NULL)
            y = bstMinimum(z->right);
   }
   return y;
 }

//find the minimum of the right tree
struct node *bstMinimum(struct node *A)
{
   while(A!=NULL && A->left!=NULL)
   {
     A=A->left; 
   }
  return A;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the declaration of your BST tree ? And do mention which side are you storing lower values and which side the upper values with respect to a node

Comment: How can h1 and  h2 both be height of tree.

Comment: h1 and h2 are the range that I want for example I want to find the successor of node k which is a depth between h1=0 e h2=3

Comment: I don't see how you'll be able to do this if all you have is a node and no way to find the node's parent.

Comment: in the discent to right,  I  update the successor to the parent node in the variable Y